# how to make OCR tesseract more accurate?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

i have problem to make my OCR (tesseract) more accurate to process a japanese character.

[image: example image]

you can see the tiny part of the japanese character is not actually readable for OCR, i even split the image into a 3 part and make it vertical one line.

[image: split image]

according from japanese style reading was from left to right so that's why i use one line vertical to make more accurate and upgrade the dpi to 300, but still not got the best result.

```
def upgrade_dpi(array_img,dpi_value = 300):
        image_pil = Image.fromarray(array_img)
        image_info = image_pil.info
        image_info['dpi'] = (dpi_value, dpi_value)
        image_pil.info = image_info
        return image_pil

def OCR_machine(image_text,def_lang="jpn_vert"):
        custom_config = r'--oem 1 --psm 12'
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_text,config=custom_config,lang=def_lang)
        result_text = text.lower().replace("\n"," ")
        return result_text
```

the result i got was `持ってるのよ?寺聖杯をどうして潜軍が半問滞`

i know a japanese character it's so hard to recognize because of a class character like hiragana,katagana and kanji there's a thousand of character. any tips or algorithm that i can use to improve to accuration ?